# Java how to check if user input is in my array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, contains

I want the user to input a `customerID` and a `videoID` (the first field in the array) but I want the program to alert the user that they entered an incorrect ID I have tried `Arrays.asList(...).contains(...)` but does not work

```
// The video array
videos[0]=new Video("150", "Bagdad by Night", 6.00,         5);
videos[1]=new Video("151", "Lord of the Rings 1", 5.00,         0);

//The customer array
customers [0]= new Customer("9902JI", "Innes    ", 0,43484001);
customers [1]= new Customer("8906RH", "Herbert", 0,43484000);

public static void HireVideo(){

    System.out.println("Enter Customer ID");
    String customerID = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter Video ID");
    String videoID = sc.next();

    HireList.add(new Hire(customerID, videoID));
}
```

I am trying to access it using a method in another class the method is:

```
public int getCustomer(String IdToFind) {               
    for (int index = 0; index<Driver.customers.length && Driver.customers[index]!=null;index++) {
        if (Driver.customers[index].getCustomerID().equals(IdToFind))
            return index; //ID found                                        
    }                                                   
    return -1; //ID not found
}
```

Comment: How to find the incorrect id? Please be clear!

Comment: That code should work. Are you sure that the array you are checking in the getCustomer-method-class isn't empty?

Comment: Are you sure the entered id exactly matches one of the ids in ``customers``?

Comment: Based on [Vakh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/749588/vakh)s arguement: Maybe `equalsIgnoreCase()` does the trick here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mentioned by ifLoop, equalsIgnoreCase() should work. Also the check for Driver.customers[index]!=null should not be as part of For check because the loop will terminate if any of the records returns null, giving an impression that the id is not found. But in reality, there can be a record after that null record, matching the condition. Better still, we should make sure the Customer Array never have a record which is null.

```
public int getCustomer(String IdToFind){   
  if(Driver.customers.length > 0) {            
    for (int index = 0; index<Driver.customers.length;index++){
      if (Driver.customers[index].getCustomerID().equalsIgnoreCase(IdToFind))
         return index;         //ID found                                      
     }
    return -1;   //ID not found
   } else {
      return -1  //ID not found, as no customers in driver object
   }                              
}
```